# Comma undetected in regex matching

Tags: regex

I have a string that look like this

```
Subtotal/Sous-total:                                          1,563.00
```

I tried to get the space and the number after Sous-total. I have tried the following regex but it does not give me the answer that I want

```
(?<=Sous-total:)\s+\d+\,?\.\d+
```

Do you guys have any suggestions ?

Comment: You are not matching the digits before the dot. Perhaps like `(?<=Sous-total:)\s+\d+(?:,\d+)?\.\d+` https://regex101.com/r/C3wWx2/1

Answer (score 0):

The typical way you would match comma-separated numbers with a decimal component is:

```
\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+
```

Applying this to your current pattern we obtain:

```
(?<=Sous-total:)\s+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can get space and number with this regex by capturing first group:

```
(?<=Sous-total:)(\s+\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d+)
```

Look [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dy1C8v/3) here